# Django Form - Override standard validation message from within custom validator function

Tags: python, django, forms

In my forms.py file, I have a custom validation function that I pass to the EmailField's validators attribute. However, when I test this in browser, I get BOTH the standard error message AND my custom message. How do I hide the standard message and just display my custom message?

**browser form behavior:**

```
Email: bademail123

# Enter a valid email address.   <-- default validation error
# Email does not match expected format: example@email.com   <-- my custom validation error msg
```

**forms.py**

```
# VALIDATORS FOR FORM FIELDS
def clean_email(email):
    if not re.match("\S+@\S+\.\S+", email):
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            "Email does not match expected format: example@email.com"
        )

class IntakeFormSimple(Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label="Email",
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "example@email.com"}),
        validators=[clean_email],
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override error message of default email validator using:

```
def clean_email(email):
    if not re.match("\S+@\S+\.\S+", email):
        raise forms.ValidationError(code="invalid", message="Email does not match expected format: example@email.com")

class IntakeFormSimple(Form):
    email = email = forms.EmailField(
    label="Email",
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "example@email.com"}),
    validators=[clean_email],
    
    # This may not be needed now
    error_messages={'invalid':"Email does not match expected format: example@email.com"},
)
```

Comment: What if I wanted to still use a custom validator function?

Comment: in your custom validator try putting error code `invalid` like:
`raise forms.ValidationError(code="invalid")`. I will update my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work - it still shows me the built in EmailField default message AND my custom one. Thanks though!